# Leaflet: impossible to remove specific image layer

Tags: leaflet

Below are three functions that I use to respectively create a map, add an IMG-layer and remove an IMG-layer. Problem is that when I add an IMG-layer and then want to remove it before adding a new (different) IMG-layer......the removal is not taking place.

The IMG-layers that I use are simple URLs to png's.

So subsequently:

- loadMap();
- SetLayer("2018_10_13_16_15.png");
- RemoveLayer("2018_10_13_16_15.png");
- SetLayer("2018_10_13_16_30.png");

Then "2018_10_13_16_15.png" is not removed.

What am I doing wrong??

```
var map = L.map('map');
var imageBounds = [[50.520, 0.813], [54.295, 10.996]];

function loadMap(){
    map.createPane('labels');

    var positron = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: cartodbAttribution
    }).addTo(map);

    var positronLabels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: cartodbAttribution,
        pane: 'labels'
    }).addTo(map);

    map.setView({lat: 52.5, lng: 5.2}, 6.5);
    isMap = true; //map is loaded
}


function SetLayer(url) {
    IMGLayer = L.imageOverlay(url, imageBounds);
    IMGLayer.addTo(map);
}


function RemoveLayer(url) {
    IMGLayer = L.imageOverlay(url, imageBounds);
    IMGLayer.removeFrom(map);
}
```

Comment: The `IMGLayer` in your `RemoveLayer()` function is not the same object that you added to the map. It's a new object with the same properties. You need to use a single object throughout - re-constructing it won't work.

Comment: Just reverse the order in your `RemoveLayer()` to call first `IMGLayer.removeFrom(map);` and then `IMGLayer = L.imageOverlay(url, imageBounds);` [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q2eyzm81/)

Comment: Works......thx a lot!!